# Getting longest subsequence in sparse list of values

Tags: python, timestamp, sequence, unix-timestamp

I have a very long list of unix times (rounded to 10s) and I need to find the longest sequential sequence of timestamps 10s apart in that list.

```
[1441831770.0, 1441831780.0, 1441831790.0, ... 1442466860.0, 1442466870.0, 1442466880.0]
```

If I have a list of 100 timestamps and 60 of which are in a sequence 600 seconds long and then theres a 4 minute break followed by another 40 in a sequence 400 seconds long, I would return the 60 second long sublist of timestamps.

Is there an efficient way to do this? `itertools` or `numpy`? Or must it be hard coded?

Thanks.

Comment: this can be done in O(n) time quite easily, is that not efficient enough? What does *hard coded* mean?

Comment: I just mean is there some library that will do this simply or should I write the full algorithm myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [itertools example in the docs that finds consecutive runs](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html#examples). Here's its adaptation for your case (not tested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from itertools import groupby

data = [1441831770.0, 1441831780.0, 1441831790.0, ...]

longest = []
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda (i,x): i*10 - int(x)):
    longest = max(longest, [x for _, x in g], key=len)
print longest
```